# The transaction has aborted error though

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-6, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I am using EF6 with code first approach. I have a case where I am trying to apply same transaction over 2 different databases. Find my code below for the reference,

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6000)))
        {
            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    /*
                     * some operations on dbContext
                     * 
                     */

                    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(NewConnectionString))
                    {
                        string query = " ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]...........";
                        conn.Execute(query); // I am using a dapper to call this execute query
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                        
                    throw;
                }
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

The first section in try block does some normal operations on tables by using linq. 
The second section where I have used IDbConnection, I am executing some query using dapper on another database. I can execute everything fine without error, but I'm getting error after I complete the scope. It throws error as **The transaction has aborted**. Everything works fine whenever I skip dapper execution section. I have checked many solutions and also tried to put separate transaction for dapper section but nothing worked. My requirement is to put all the statements under single transaction. Is that possible? How?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: @Crowcoder Inner exeption is null

Comment: This code tries to start the distributed transaction coordinator (MS-DTC), which probably fails. Both database servers should be able to run MS-DTC. MS-DTC is always necessary when different connection strings are used with a transaction scope.